# How to disable port forwarding in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, clickhouse

I'm running Clickhouse on EKS. I'm trying to block all access apart from the service endpoint.

However, anyone who has access to the cluster can port forward and get access to the database.
I've been looking but couldn't find an answer. Is there a way to block the port forward functionality on the cluster?

Comment: Ordinary users shouldn't have access to the cluster API endpoint at all.  Paths like calling the application through an Ingress don't need it.